# Get touch point location

Tags: ios, uiwebview, touch

I have UIWebView for display the articles. I have UIWebView for displays HTML articles. When user touch some area in UIWebView, UIMenuController will display. Then user select note button it displays UITextView. How to get touch location?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Get the specific point that was touched
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:wbCont];
    NSLog(@"X location: %f", point.x);
    NSLog(@"Y Location: %f",point.y);

}


- (void)note:(id)sender  {


}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work?

Comment: yes. It's not showing anything in nslog

Comment: Is touches working in simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIWebview is wrapped inside a UIScrollView. Therefore the touch events do not go through to the UIView where your method receives the touch events.

For your UIViewController it should implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Then add a gesture to your webview:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTest:)];
[tap setDelegate:self];
[self.yourwebview.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Next:

```
- (void)tapTest:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%f %f", [sender locationInView:self.yourwebview].x,  [sender locationInView:self.yourwebview].y);
}
```

Edit:

shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer should return YES as well.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How to save this coordinates and get it later?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@" CHECKING CGPOINT %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(firstTouch));


}
```

works fine for me ;-)

Comment: @user2807197 : make sure use have included UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your .h file and firsttouch is more like cgpoint firstTouch.This is working fine for me.

Comment: Minor correction: change code to ----> CGPoint firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self.view];

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event

{

     NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:textview] anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: wbCont];

     CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:textview];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only one truly fail-safe way to do this (that I know of):

```
@interface MyWebView : UIWebView
@end

@implementation MyWebView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        NSLog(@"Touched inside!");
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Web views are extremely complex, so overriding those `UIResponder` methods or adding gesture recognisers won't work. Unfortunately, `hitTest:withEvent:` gets called 3 times on each touch, so you'll have to deal with that.

Comment: Yes it is, haven't tested on a device.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    NSLog(@"X location: %f",touch.view.position.x);
    NSLog(@"Y Location: %f",touch.position.y);
}
```