# In Xamarin forms place the text inside view working in android but not working ios as expected

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, absolutelayout

We are using DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo to assign the label text in AbsoluteLayout but it works in android but not working ios as expected text value not set to exact position

App.xaml.cs

```
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
float Devicedensity = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

To call these method to calculate

```
 public static int PixelsToDp(float pixelValue)
        {
            var dp = (int)((pixelValue) / Devicedensity);
            return dp;
        }
```

To calculate to add label in absolutelayout

```
int dpX = PixelsToDp(Value.Xaxis);
            int dpY = PixelsToDp(Value.Yaxis);

          AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(label, new Rectangle(dpX, dpY, -1, -1));
          AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(label, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
```

myabs.Children.Add(label);

ios renderer while tap

```
public void TapHandler(UITapGestureRecognizer tgr)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = tgr.LocationInView(nativeElement);
        formsElement.OnTapEvent(Value.Xaxis = (float)touchPoint.X, Value.Yaxis = (float)touchPoint.Y);
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem in ios?

Comment: Label values position mismatch but working android

Comment: double Devicedensity = (double)UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale; i have tried this also but not working ios how to calculate correct density value or anyother way to achieve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564723/get-touch-point-location